# How to inflate multiple XML files in layout without compromising on performance. (around 70 layouts)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have around 70 XML layout files to be inflated in an activity (Like a list of input fields. Like some huge form). It takes around 3-4 seconds to load. 
I cannot use RecyclerView because it crashes while opening keyboard. Also, the sliding up and down is slow)

Please suggest some way in which the Activity is opened quickly.

Comment: It's not usual to have as much xml to inflate. Why do you have 70 file ? What do you do with all of this and how do they look (hopefully is there any similarity between the files). Could you explain how the keyboard makes the recyclerview crash?

Comment: I agree with the answer of @neogineer ,  i have the same questions. Other thing is, you could use ViewStubs for this, but with 70 possible layouts ( and the depending conditions, when you want to show which view) this could also be a mess to handle, maybe think about your conception of the activity and simply splitting stuff in other activities.

Comment: It is like a dynamic form generated based on questions coming from Server. around 70 different questions are coming

Comment: You should be using a RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

For those who facing similar issues, I found a solution:
I used AsyncTask (where the inflating part is done in background and Just adding the view is done in foreground)

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, View, Void> {
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  Activity activity;
 LinearLayout parent;
  List<Integer> layoutIds;

public MyAsync(Activity activity,LinearLayout linLayout,List<Integer> layoutIds) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.parent = linLayout;
    this.layoutIds = layoutIds;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layoutIds.size(); i++) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIds.get(i), null);
        publishProgress(view);
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(View... view) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(view);

    parent.addView(view[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `I cannot use RecyclerView because it crashes` You should fix that. `Also, the sliding up and down is slow`. Again fix that.

Comment: why ? If Async is working smooth and awesome. Why shall I use RecyclerView? (I do not have heavy images or stuffs to be loaded)